# zcrmsdk for python -- ImportError: cannot import name 'ZCRMRestClient' from 'zcrmsdk'

Tags: python, sdk, crm, zoho, zcrmsdk

I installed zcrmsdk as many doc said in Zoho:

**pip install zcrmsdk**

Every example start with:

**from zcrmsdk import ZCRMRestClient,ZohoOAuth**

but, this line failed with :

*ImportError: cannot import name 'ZCRMRestClient' from 'zcrmsdk'*

so, is there any documentation updated to run this example using python 3.9 + zcrmsdk 3.1.0 ??

I'm trying to create the simplest code to bring a Lead (for example)

Comment: did you look at https://pypi.org/project/zcrmsdk/#description.

Comment: your question already has an answer here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67047916/module-zcrmsdk-has-no-attribute-zcrmrestclient
please consider deleting your question

Comment: @SandeepPolamuri yes, but it doesn't say anything related to this issue.

Comment: @MohammadAlavi that question has been resolved uninstalling latest version and installing version 2 that has more than 4 years!

Comment: I just tried the import with python 3.11 in a venv virtualenv, and it didn't report the error.  So you might try upgrading python to 3.11 and retry the install and import.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your'e using zcrmsdk version 3.x.x. Zcrmsdk have changed over time and for that particular code to run, you need to downgrade your zcrmsdk to version 2.1. For that use:

```
pip install zcrmsdk==2.1
```